# onActivityResult does not get data on Android 1.6

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two Activites. Activity B will get called by Activity A like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(SearchViewLevel2.this, SearchViewLevel3.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 7788);
}
```

In Activity B in `onCreate()` I have `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, inti)`.
Then I override the BackButton:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
mcontext = getBaseContext();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if(fa.getCheckedPositions().size() > 0) {
            checked = true;
        }
        inti.putExtra("data", checked);
        inti.putExtra("mypos", thispos);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In Activity A I have `onActivityResult()` like that:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mContext = getBaseContext();
    if (requestCode == 7788) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { //until here it comes
            boolean l = data.getBooleanExtra("data", false); 
            // in 1.6 the boolean is false, so it doesn't get any data
            if (l) { 
                CheckBox cb =
                    (CheckBox)fa.getViewAtIndex(
                        data.getIntExtra("mypos", -1)).findViewById(10110);
                cb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selectionpartial);
            }       
        } 
    } 
}
```

My problem is that I don't get any data in Android 1.6, but in higher Versions I do.

So are there any differences beetween 1.6 and higher Versions in this code?

Comment: have you checked with `hasExtra(String name)` if the "data" is delivered by the intent?

Comment: if i check with `hasExtra("data")`, it is false

Comment: Are you sure that the onKeyDown method works like expected with 1.6? Maybe this is the basic problem...

Comment: Could be the problem but i don't know, how to solve it. I tried it with `onClick()` instead of `onKeyDown` and it worked.